# How to do fast scroll of the cardviews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, fastscroll

I'm a beginning android developer. I have made an app with many cards in cardviews, but I doesn't know, how to do fast scroll in my app. 
My code is here: [Cardview's data are changed while srolling RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392790/cardviews-data-are-changed-while-srolling-recyclerview)
P.S: This guide is difficult for me - [How to add a fast-scroller to the RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to implement it yourself, you can use this library:

https://github.com/plusCubed/recycler-fast-scroll

just add the gradle dependency to your app's module, and use it as mentioned under the basic usage section